# Carrier Fog Aws - Files are automatically disappearing from S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

The files uploaded succesfully using fog to s3 on carrierwave seem to be disappearing automatically.How do I prevent this from happening. The fog public setting is set to true.

Comment: How can you know that the file is disappearing?

Comment: Since it was there when I uploaded it and after a day or so when I get access denied , I know that the file has disappeared . It doesn't show up in the s3 console as well

Comment: Maybe by chance [THIS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) has something to do with it?  How quickly have you noticed files being deleted after they are uploaded?  I've had to disable this feature in the past when facing a similar issue.

Comment: I have checked S3 cloud trail and it seems Carrierwave is deleting it

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Carrierwave deletes files not only when the model is deleted, but also when it's *updated*, even if you don't touch the mounted uploader field. There is supposed to be a config setting `remove_previously_stored_files_after_update` that when set false, prevents this from happening, but I haven't had any luck setting it false – it still deletes my files on model update.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your uploader class you can modify the `#remove!` method.

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  #...

  def remove!
    # do some stuff to confirm that you want the file removed,
    # otherwise return.  You have access to model record as 'model'
    super
  end

end
```